# Error while pulling images from docker in Ubuntu Server (18.04.6 LTS) Azure Vm

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

So I got to know about Azure and I want to run a nodejs file in VM. I know the steps on how to deploy the nodejs in Digital Ocean, and It worked fine. I tried to follow the same steps but seems like there were some issues while pulling images from docker.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) in order to install docker in my VM. But it seems like there is an issue:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

on running `sudo docker pull hello-world`

while the same error is occuring on docker-compose

(This is just an example, I want to run docker-compose but It gave the same error)

I tried running all the solutions that I found but all didn't help. Is there anyone else who has created a vm in azure and came across this  issue and fixed it?

I found about 5-6 links with the same question but none of the answers fixed my problem :(

I created a Linux VM with the help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-linux-virtual-machine-in-azure/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Look for the image on hub.docker.com and make sure that you pass a correct name of the image. The article is from 2018 so it could be out dated.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I am not able to create. They should have updated their docs with the new version